# Containers stretch beyond in Android Studio preview

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Whenever I add a new container view on the designer surface and sets both `layout:width` and `layout:height` to `wrap_content`, the container view size goes beyond what it should be as shown below.

What should I do to fix this issue?

[image: Android Studio]

Code snippet of `content_main.xml`

[image]

***EDIT***: Might be a bit different from image above but still the same issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.dance2die.myapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I believe this happens because the listview needs to be populated with list view items before the listview can calculate its height and width. Thus, without a measured height and width, it can't wrap content as you want it to. I don't think there is a good way to fix this other than populating the listview with sample content in xml.

Comment: Post your XML code snippet instead of providing in image.

Answer (score 2):

Use

> android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Unfortunately changing both `android:layout_width/height` to `match_parent` did not change the preview behavior.

Comment: If this is anything like html, what happens if you match parent but set padding-top and padding-bottom to 0dp?

Comment: @PaulTotzke Still the same issue. I was following a tutorial. Within the tutorial, when the author set all the padding to 0, the listview took up the whole screen. But in my case it doesn't occur.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that.

The preview shows you just a preview of what it will be using a `Simple 2-Line List item`. It is stretched because you set it to `wrap content` so the `ListView` would actually be longer than your screen if there would be more than 8 items in it (at least in a preview on that device, maybe on a preview of a Nexus 6 you would see 10 items).

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess but try to use a scrollview instead of a relativelayout.

or within the layout so it will stay the same size when the listview is populated and doesn't stretch.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your
 `app:layout_behavior=""`
try to change it or remove it,your container size wont go beyond.

Comment: Setting `app:layout_behavior=""` moved up the listview above and behind the actionbar.  Here is how it looks now. http://i.imgur.com/LE8JpEy.png

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the  `warp_content`to `match_parent`

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:padding="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Either your top menu bar is pushing your child div lower or your soft nav keys are being 'floated'.

First, try hiding the status bar (top). http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Second, try a new device in Android Virtual Device manager that has doesn't have a virtual buttons bar, like the the Galaxy s7 or try hiding it.
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html